# Pasing int table using write function

Tags: c++, file-io, descriptor

Trying to send a table of integers to file, but I'm getting some errors:

```
        fd[0] = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_SYNC, 0700);
        const int size = 20;
        int *p = new int[size];
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            p[i] = i;
        }
        write (fd[0], p, sizeof(int)*size); 
        close(fd[0]);
```

After calling this code in my file I see something like this: `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00`.

Comment: did you view it with a text editor or od? You might want to check the return value of open. try "od -i filename"

Comment: 0000000           0           1           2           3
0000020           4           5           6           7
0000040           8           9          10          11
0000060          12          13          14          15
0000100          16          17          18          19
0000120    resoult of od -i

Comment: The 00 numbers are addresses, the other are your ints. They are in the file just like you wrote them. Now, do you mean to write a binary file or a text file?

Comment: BTW, your code is doing exactly what you told it to do. It wrote 20 ints to the file.

Comment: I thought so, but how to present numbers in more comfortable way ?

Comment: In your file, would you like each value on a separate line or separated by some character like a space or comma?

Comment: when im writing numbers to the file im using snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d\n", i); so they are in separate lines each when im reading, id like to choose only prime and send them to other file one number on each line:) I have algorithm for looking primes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write datas in files, if you want to read it with a text editor, you need to convert variables to strings (serialization).

To do this, you can use `fprintf` and `fscanf`, or implement your own parsing functions, you only need to manipulate strings.

In order to generate a readable file, your code could be modified in:

```
FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "w"); // "a", "w" or what you want
const int size = 20;
int *p = new int[size];
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
  p[i] = i;
  fprintf(f, "%d ", p[i]); 
}

fclose(f);
```

To read the file, you could do:

```
FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
int nb = 0;
int tab[100]; // a buffer

while((1 == fscanf("%d ", &tab[nb])) && (nb < 100))
  nb++;
```

Comment: I doubt if that is what the OP wants. How would he ever be able to read back the data and know where one value ends and the next one starts?

Comment: I corrected that. @JimRhodes : a loop with fscanf("%d ", &var_int) should work.

Comment: w have to use only write function

Comment: with "a" you will be able to write at the end directly.

Answer (score 2):

This will write space separated integers, with a trailing space. You didn't really say what format you need other than "text".

```
    fd[0] = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_SYNC, 0700);
    if(fd[0] < 0) {
        perror("open");
    }
    const int size = 20;
    //int *p = new int[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        char buf[20];
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d ", i);
        write(fd[0], buf, strlen(buf));
    }
    //write (fd[0], p, sizeof(int)*size); 
    close(fd[0]);
```

Comment: A problem could be the read function, without fscanf it will be his responsability to read the good nb of bytes and use sscanf. It's why I prefer usage of fopen/fprintf/fscanf.

Comment: If you like the answer click the arrow up to the left. Thanks.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant, I agree. OP said he must use write. HW assignment. He'll be back when it's time to read. :-)

Comment: :) First time on stack

Comment: Welcome, next time try to provide a complete compilable example, not just a code snipitt.

Comment: Ok you were right :) It is possibile to read only one line of the file  and then read int from buffer, and so on until the end of file. It is realy hard to find good example  of using read and write ...

Comment: @WitŻelek, post another question, show what you tried and show the file you are trying to parse. If you are not allowed to use certain functions, say that too.